# JS class loader for client & server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

In JS full stack project some classes shared between server and client side. Most of functionality in such classes relevant for both sides (like constants, validate functions, metadata etc.) But sometimes I need different functionality according to side the code running.

Right now to solve this, I using:

1. naming convention  (server side related functions start with `__` client only functions starts with `_$`)
2. Global function that says if we running on client or server
3. Many places like this:

   this[(isServer()?'__':'_$')+funcName].apply(this, params);

It is working, but code become ugly. I trying to write some kind of class loader, which will replace this logic on construction time and will be seamless.

Is there something similar already exists? If no, what should I afraid of when implementing such functionality?

Comment: In general I try to keep server side and client side separated as they have different purposes or you end up with classes being a bulky mess trying to fit every ones need. Design Server side class for server side needs and client side classes for client-side need. You might also even have display specific classes such as viewmodels which are separate too. Use mappers in between the layers to map one to the other as needed. Separation is important and it makes your code and unit tests/integration tests a lot easier to write and manage as well.

Comment: I agree, but in some cases it is better to have 1 single source of truth. My shared classes synchronized with 3rd party APIs & behavior and when it is changed - I don't want to change my code in multiple places (model, serverSideMapper, clientSideMapper, serverSideValidators, clientSideValidators...) it suppose to be one single class.

Comment: Wouldn't API integration work of interfaces or interface-like implementations, hence any class changing is not much of a big deal. Yes, it is more work to update all the layers but hence your code is extremely easy to maintain and upgrade going forward instead of tightly coupled throughout the layers but if the scale of the project is small anyway then it doesn't matter I suppose. I try to follow SOLID when ever possible though.